# How to use emotion/styled with React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

I have wrapped my root component in `ThemeProvider` from `@emotion/react` which gives me access to `props.theme` as such:

```js
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.palette.primary.main};
`;
```

**Problem:** `props.theme` is an empty object according to TS - `palette` does not exist on the Theme type (however the object I am passing to the theme provider does contain that attribute). If I make TS ignore this, the code works.

The docs cover this and it seems like an easy fix:
[Extend the Emotion theme type](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#define-a-theme)

However I do not understand the docs well enough to make the `Theme` type of `props.theme` have the correct attributes.

Any help that points me in the right direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this file **types.d.ts**

```
import "@emotion/react";
import { IPalette } from "../your-palette";

declare module "@emotion/react" {
  export interface Theme extends IPalette {}
}
```

Comment: Where to add this file? on root of project folder?